# How to check and run tesseract in Cent OS 7 if installed

Tags: centos, ocr, tesseract

I setup and installed tesseract OCR in my Cent OS 7. Now I'm looking for a command which i can run and check if tesseract is installed?

Here is a picture of my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbflt.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute the command `tesseract` or `tesseract -v`.